# Assume $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $\bar x$ and that $\|x_n\| < \epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then $\|\bar x\| \le \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove this below theorem:

> Assume that $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $\bar x$ and that $\|x_n\| < \epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then $\|\bar x\| \le \epsilon$.

Could you please verify whether my attempt is fine or contains mistakes? Thank you so much!

---

We have $\|\bar x\| = \|(\bar x -x_n) + x_n\| \le \|\bar x - x_n \| + \|x_n\|$. Taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we have $$\|\bar x\| \le \lim_{n \to \infty}\|\bar x - x_n \| +  \lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\| \le \epsilon$$

Hence $\|\bar x\| \le \epsilon$.

Comment: Looks good.  You can make the inequality substitution $||x_n||\leq \epsilon$ for all $n$ (before taking the limit) if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. To be pedantically rigorous, it could be written like this: Choose $N_1$ such that $n\geqslant N_1$ implies $\|x_n\|<\frac\varepsilon2$ and $N_2$ such that $n\geqslant N_2$ implies $\|x_n-\bar x\|<\frac\varepsilon2$. Let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then for $n\geqslant N$ we have
$$
\|\bar x\| \leqslant \|\bar x-x_n\| + \|x_n\| = \frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.
$$